# I need to parse the payload from push notification, but if user press game icon instead of press notification, how can I get the data?

Tags: iphone, ios, push-notification

I need to parse the payload from different push notification, but if user press game icon instead of pressing notification to start the app, how can I get the payload?

I already implement these two:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
-(void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo
```

If user press game icon to start game, the launchOptions is nil, So how to do?
Is there any method provide to read push notification from notification center ?

Very appreciate for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

if the user ignored the push notification and opened the application from the icon, then you will not have any mean to get that notification payload,